# Tabula Py not detecting tables in PDF

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing, tabula

I have used the following code but nothing is getting detected. I have also tried on various other PDF formats but getting the same result.

```
from tabula import read_pdf,convert_into

df=read_pdf("1415_048.pdf",output_format="dataframe",encoding='utf-8',java_options=None,multiple_tables=True)
```

Where the PDF looks like this
[image]

```
[] #This is the result I'm getting
```

Comment: Same problem here. I'm trying to extract text from [this PDF](https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/149939-topic-based-vocabulary-list.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

tabula-py is based on tabula-java. And it works only with text based PDF.

According to tabula.app website https://tabula.technology/ :

> Note: Tabula only works on text-based PDFs, not scanned documents.